# Let $S = ${$-2, -1, 0, 2, 4, 7, ½ $}. Find $f(x)$ for $x \in S$.

Tags: functions

I am trying to learn functions and I saw this sample question but I am not sure what to do

Here is the question:

```
Let S = {-2, -1, 0, 2, 4, 7, ½}. Find f(x) for x ∈ S.

1. f(x) = 5x – 7
```

Will I just substitute all the items in the set to $f(x)$? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you only have to evaluate in $f(x)$ all your values ​​of the set $S$, for example:
$f (-2) = 5 (-2) -7 \Longrightarrow f(-2)=-17$

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply substitute the elements found in set $S$ into each function $f(x)$. The symbol $\in$ means '*an element of*', so the question '*find $f(x)$ for $x \in S$*' means to substitute each value of $x$ that is an element of $S$ into $f(x)$.

For example, $f(-2) = 5 \cdot (-2) - 7 = -10 - 7 = -17$, $f(-1) = 5 \cdot (-1) - 7 = -5 - 7 = -12$ and so on.

I hope that helps!

Comment: OKay. Thanks for your response!